# gpload fails in CSV mode where NULL_AS is ""

Tags: talend, greenplum

I have CSV file(10+ million records) like below format.

```
"1","abc","","test","","","100"
```

I have tried to load CSV file's data into greenplum table using `gpload` where I passed gpload parameter `NULL_AS : ""` but it failed

It loads file if I replace `""` with blank and leaving `NULL_AS` blank, like this :

```
"1","abc",,"test",,,"100"
```

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: I think the documentation for gpload itself mentiones that NULL_AS must be a character or nothing. Providing "" means its not a chracter neither nothing.